# Rails application without port number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I am using following command for start the production server.

```
nohup ruby script/server webrick -e production &
```

My Rails applications start with port number in URL, like this one:

> http://myapp.com:3000/

How to remove port no from the app URL? I think I need to install something like Passenger, If so anyone suggest me a good tutorial.

PS: My rails App hosted in http://dreamhost.com and I am using Rails 2.3r

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but couldn't you start your app on port 80? Then any traffic over HTTP would hit it, I think. I didn't want to post this as an answer because I've never tried it before and have no idea if that's really the proper way to go about things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a production environment you probably want to use passenger instead of doing things by yourself.

Comment: How do I install and configure passenger in my server? is there any good tutorial regarding this one

Answer (score 1):

"No port" for HTTP means port 80, so specify that with the `-p 80` or `--port=80`:

```
nohup ruby script/server webrick -e production -p 80 &
```

You don't *need* Passenger, but using it can make things easier to manage for smaller apps and requires less babysitting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this and you know the response

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, I got below error ruby script/server webrick -e production -p 80
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)

Comment: Well if your command in your original question didn't get that same error, you've done something differently.